# How do I move one UIView during rotation in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, rotation

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to deal with different device orientations for one screen of my iPad app.  Here's my situation:

~ All of this screen is rotating perfectly using springs and struts except for one label.  The problem with this label is that I want it to move in an unorthodox manner (diagonally), thus springs and struts (or resizing masks will not work).

~ The way that I'm considering doing this is as such:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)newInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(newInterfaceOrientation))
    {
        self.myScreenLabel.frame = CGRectMake(600,0,400,100);
    }
    else {
        self.myScreenLabel.frame = CGRectMake(...//something); }
}
```

I would also put a check in viewDidLoad with similar logic.  `If in portrait mode, put label at... else put label at...`.

I think that this will work; however, I'm kinda wondering if there's a better designed way to do this.  The method above, has hard-coded numbers everywhere; thus, is there a better way to do this? Also, this method does not take advantage of the fact that I have my label positioned perfectly in the storyboard for portrait mode and it's just landscape that I need to change.

Any suggestions on better design?

Comment: I would keep it simple: Put two views as proxies in you nib, and use either of them to set the frame of the label. This way you keep just one nib and do all layout stuff in IB. The proxy views can stay hidden. The code needed to make this work is very little and very readable, something like: `self.actualLabel.frame = landscape?self.landscapeProxy.frame:self.portraitProxy.frame;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First question, I've implemented behavior on orientation change with your approach with no bad results, if you are okay that the method is triggered right before rotation happens.  Alternatively, you can use NSNotifications to add a trigger on orientation change:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:)name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Then add a method like:

```
 - (void) didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification {   
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        //your code here
    }
 }
```

Regarding your second question, positioning frames like that is scary, but I think you realize that.  Instead, position the element related to something else, just like a strut (which would say, always position the widget relative to a distance between it is strutted against).  So use the window's frame, the view's frame, or some other UIView subclass in the view to position the object against, rather than absolute numbers.

Comment: Be very cautious mixing *device* orientation and *interface* orientation. I have seen really odd bugs because of this. The most important thing to realize, is that the device knows a face up/down orientation while the interface does not.

Comment: Ahh good point, you're totally correct, I'll update my answer with your suggestion as I've seen those bugs too.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

1. If iOS 5+, you might want to use [viewWillLayoutSubviews](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW91), probably even more important given the comments in the iOS 6 release notes re modal views and the screen reorientation methods. This also has the advantage that your code is in one spot. Since I still support pre 5 (though I won't for much longer), I actually have dynamic checking of iOS version and invoke my `viewWillLayoutSubviews` from the other methods if pre 5.0, otherwise I let `viewWillLayoutSubviews` just do the heavy lifting.
2. If your landscape orientation is radically different, you probably want to pursue [Creating an Alternate Landscape Interface](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW14). I've never done this, but it seems like it's up your alley. There are also postings on SO about using different NIBs for different orientations. Not sure this makes sense in a storyboard environment, though.
3. For these controls that we occasionally have to move around or resize based upon screen dimensions, I think most of us do it with `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. That's the entire purpose of that method (though I generally use it for labels whose height changes based upon the data contents and the screen width). I had never stopped to think that there might be another way. If you only have one control that you're moving around as you change your orientation, maybe you could create two additional, hidden controls, one for where you want your visible control in portrait, the other hidden control for where you want it in landscape (and in IB, you can toggle your view orientation to facilitate the layout of controls). Then in your `viewWillLayoutSubviews` set your frame of your actual visible control to be the frame of one of those two hidden controls (depending upon orientation, of course). That gets you out of the business of hardcoding frame coordinates in your code, and take advantage of the benefits of IB. This whole suggestion might be too cute by half, but it's an alternative approach if you don't want to go through the effort of my second point.